# Rendering a component as the parent of the actual component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 components, I would like the first component to be a render prop in the second component, which will encapsulate the content of the second component if it is defined. I don't quite understand how to write this, and the documentation I find on render props tends to be difficult to understand. Has anyone written a similar implementation?

The general idea i'm after is that you pass in the props for `component1` in the `component1` prop for `component2`, and it renders `<Component1>` with it's props inside `component2`.

**Rough code example of what i'm trying to do (It isn't meant to work)**

```js
    interface Component1 {
     id?: string;
     children: React.ReactNode;
    }

    const Component1 = (props: Component1) => {
      const { children } = props;
      return (<div className="component1">{children}</div>)
    }

    interface Component2 {
      component1?: (propsForComponent1) => <Component1 {...propsForComponent1}>
    }

    const Component2 = (props: Component2) => {
      const {component1} = props;
      if (component1) {
        return {component1({id: 'exampleId', children: <div className="component2">Stuff for component 2</div>)}}
      };
      return (<div className="component2">Stuff for component 2</div>);

    }
```

Edit: Have changed the example because the intention is confusing people.

Edit: Will just pass the first component as a prop into the second component for now. I think the general answer is to not try to use a component as two components, and just stick to children.

Comment: Doesn't make sense - you are passing a component as a prop, however you are rendering an imported one, not passed down one.

Comment: What exactly is your intention here? Describe what you want to achieve

Comment: Have updated, the intention was to be able to render an instance component1 with props as a parent of component 2 from inside component2.

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening in your code sample, is that even if you are passing down a whole component (`Component1`) as a prop, you are **not** rendering it, but using an imported (or accessible inside the scope) `Component1`.

Anyways - why would you want to pass down a whole component as a prop, even if you can basically just import it?

What I would suggest - use a prop, but not a component, but a **boolean flag** that determines if the component should be wrapped or not.

```
interface Component2 {
  shouldBeWrapped?: boolean;
}

const Component2 = ({ shouldBeWrapped }: Component2) => {
  if (shouldBeWrapped) {
    return (
       <Component1 with props given in on component1 property>
          <div className="component2">Stuff for component 2</div>
       </Component1>
    );
  }

  return (<div className="component2">Stuff for component 2</div>);
}
```

Comment: My example may be a little vague, it's because I need the first component to wrap the second component, but I also need to be able to pass properties to the first component while rendering the second component. Think an optional fieldset component that has some radio buttons as it's children.

Comment: @user3062123 Then use few flags that will determine if you should render some additional content inside Component2 or not, personally I would avoid passing down whole components as props.